# Call a list within an entity PrimeFaces JSF

Tags: primefaces

I have a datatable (entity Ejercicio) and in each row a "rowExpansion". Inside there is other datatable that uses a `List<Solucion> soluciones` (Solucion is other entity).

In the first table I define `var="ejercicio"` and in the table "Solucion" I define `var="solucion" value="ejercicio.soluciones"` but when I need to use the variables, I can not access them... Why?? I don´t uderstand.

**Pag.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable id="tablaEjercicios" var="ejercicio" value="#{beanAdmin.listaEjercicios}"  widgetVar="ejercicioTabla" editable="true">
....
....
 <p:rowExpansion>
  <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="0">
   <p:tab title="Soluciones">
    <p:dataTable id="tablaSoluciones" var="solucion" value="#{ejercicio.soluciones}" editable="true" rowIndexVar="index">
      ...
     <p:column headerText="Solución" width="75%">
      <p:cellEditor>
       <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{**solucion.ICANT**}" /></f:facet>
       <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="inputSolucion" value="#{**solucion.solucion**}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
      </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>
     ...
    </p:dataTable>
   </p:tab>
  </p:accordionPanel>
 </p:rowExpansion>
```

**Entity "Ejercicio"**

```
public class Ejercicio implements Serializable
{

private String codigoEj;
private String enunciado;
private String esquema;
private long fallos;
private long intentos;
private int dificultad;
private String tipo;

private String listaEtiquetaString;

private List<String> listaEtiqueta;
private List<Entidad.Idioma> listaIdiomas;
private List<Solucion> soluciones;

public Ejercicio(String codigoEj, String enunciado, String esquema, long fallos, long intentos, int dificultad, String tipo, List<String> listaEtiqueta, List<Idioma> listaIdiomas, List<Solucion> soluciones)
{
    this.codigoEj = codigoEj;
    this.enunciado = enunciado;
    this.esquema = esquema;
    this.fallos = fallos;
    this.intentos = intentos;
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.listaEtiqueta = listaEtiqueta;
    this.listaIdiomas = listaIdiomas;
    this.soluciones = soluciones;

    this.listaEtiquetaString = UtilidadesSQL.stringListEtiqueta(listaEtiqueta);
}

public Ejercicio()
{
}

public String getCodigoEj()
{
    return codigoEj;
}

public void setCodigoEj(String codigoEj)
{
    this.codigoEj = codigoEj;
}

public String getEnunciado()
{
    return enunciado;
}

public void setEnunciado(String enunciado)
{
    this.enunciado = enunciado;
}

public String getEsquema()
{
    return esquema;
}

public void setEsquema(String esquema)
{
    this.esquema = esquema;
}

public long getFallos()
{
    return fallos;
}

public void setFallos(long fallos)
{
    this.fallos = fallos;
}

public long getIntentos()
{
    return intentos;
}

public void setIntentos(long intentos)
{
    this.intentos = intentos;
}

public int getDificultad()
{
    return dificultad;
}

public void setDificultad(int dificultad)
{
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
}

public String getTipo()
{
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo)
{
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public List<String> getListaEtiqueta()
{
    return listaEtiqueta;
}

public void setListaEtiqueta(List<String> listaEtiqueta)
{
    this.listaEtiqueta = listaEtiqueta;
}

public List<Idioma> getListaIdiomas()
{
    return listaIdiomas;
}

public void setListaIdiomas(List<Idioma> listaIdiomas)
{
    this.listaIdiomas = listaIdiomas;
}

public List<Solucion> getSoluciones()
{
    return soluciones;
}

public void setSoluciones(List<Solucion> soluciones)
{
    this.soluciones = soluciones;
}

public String getListaEtiquetaString()
{
    return listaEtiquetaString;
}

public void setListaEtiquetaString(String listaEtiquetaString)
{
    this.listaEtiquetaString = listaEtiquetaString;
}
```

**Entity "Solucion"**

```
public class Solucion implements Serializable
{

private String codigoEjercicio;
private String solucion;
private String puntuacion;
private int id;

public Solucion()
{
}

public Solucion(String codigoEjercicio, String solucion, String puntuacion, int id)
{
    this.codigoEjercicio = codigoEjercicio;
    this.solucion = solucion;
    this.puntuacion = puntuacion;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCodigoEjercicio()
{
    return codigoEjercicio;
}

public void setCodigoEjercicio(String codigoEjercicio)
{
    this.codigoEjercicio = codigoEjercicio;
}

public String getSolucion()
{
    return solucion;
}

public void setSolucion(String solucion)
{
    this.solucion = solucion;
}

public String getPuntuacion()
{
    return puntuacion;
}

public void setPuntuacion(String puntuacion)
{
    this.puntuacion = puntuacion;
}

public Number getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the autocomplete in the IDE gets confused with stuff like this and won't work. At least in Netbeans. Is that the only problem?

Comment: Hi, I use Netbeans 8.1 and if for examen, I put value="#{solucion.id} the IDE says me a warning "Unknown property "id""..... When I use the autocomplete, the IDE tells me variables of the Ejercicio entity. Why id does not work